# How to force Android internet browser to display style changes immediately

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, browser

I made a simple flashcards HTML application and I experience strange problem with behavior under Android internet browser (default installation) on my Samsung Galaxy Tab2 7.0 tablet. When style of element is changed, such as

```
$(".question").css('color', '#FFFFFF')
$(".answer").css('color', '#FFFFFF')
$(".tag").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF')
```

the browser does not make any changes on display immediately. Later in code I am replacing text of containers and calculating sizes to fit text into element. I want this process to be invisible (that's why I want to do this white-on-white). I cannot hide elements, as then calculation would not work.

I have tested this under Windows 7 with Chrome and IE9 and it works great there. So there is some problem with the Android browser. When I put test code `alert('debug');` behind the lines above, the Android browser shows message with no changes on colors on elements, but browsers under Windows 7 show message with white-on-white elements as expected.

How can I force Android browser to reflect such style changes immediately? Is there some script function available for that, or some `<meta>` tag that would fix this? Please advise.

Comment: does it work on other android browsers? like on a different android device... you can also try setting the visibility to hidden so the space is still there or you can position it absolutely and move it off screen or try to put those css in a class and just do add class instead

Comment: @Huangism - No, it does not. Chrome works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you want to "display style changes immediately" I'm guessing you mean that your script is going to continue to execute and you want the screen to update.

You need to use continuations. Rather than letting your script keep executing you need to yield and continue. You do this by breaking up your code into multiple functions and each piece finishes by setting a timeout for the next piece. Here's a simple example. When this is done with a loop, all the x's appear at once. When using continuations, one x appears at a time.

```
<html>
<script>
function using_a_loop() {
   var e = document.getElementById('spot');
   for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
      e.innerText += ' x';
   }
}

function using_continuations(i) {
   var e = document.getElementById('spot');
   i = i || 0;  // start at 0 when i not provided
   e.innerText += ' x';
   ++i;
   if (i < 1000) {
       setTimeout(function() { using_continuations(i); }, 0);
   }
}
</script>
<div id="spot">X marks the spot:</div>
<button onclick="using_a_loop()">use a loop</button>
<button onclick="using_continuations()">use continuations</button>
</html>
```